# Access JSON nested arrays in Python

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to process something and having no luck finding the answer or if it's already been asked. I'm making a call to an API and receiving some data back as JSON. I'm stripping out certain bits that I don't need with the keys being stripped out and only the values remaining which wouldn't be a problem but I can't get into them as the keys I want to access are nested in an array.

I've been accessing the data and can get up to json.dumps(payload['output']['generic']) but I can't seem to find any information online as to how I can access these last values only.

Apologies in advance if this question already exists.

```js
{
  "output": {
    "generic": [
      {
        "response_type": "text",
        "text": "hi"
      }
    ],
    "intents": [
      {
        "intent": "CollectionDate",
        "confidence": 0.8478035449981689
      }
    ],
    "entities": [
      {
        "entity": "Payslip",
        "location": [
          19,
          26
        ],
        "value": "When is my collection date",
        "confidence": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  "context": {
    "global": {
      "system": {
        "turn_count": 10
      }
    },
    "skills": {
      "main skill": {
        "user_defined": {
          "DemoContext": "Hi!"
        },
        "system": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To clarify:

I want to access the "text", "intent" and "confidence"

at the moment I'm printing the value posted and then the responses for the sections I want like the below.

```
print(x)
print(json.dumps(payload['output']['generic']))
print(json.dumps(payload['output']['intents']))
```

Comment: To convert a JSON string to a python dict, use `data = json.loads(jsonStr)`. You then access the values with `data['key']['key2']['key3']`. Which values specifically are you trying to access?

Comment: What are the exact elements you're attempting to access but can't in this example?

Comment: I've added the examples to the main question I'm trying to get into the specific fields of "text", "confidence" and "intent" but can't I've been getting to the items a layer above but no luck getting beneath ['generic']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code to convert the json to a dict first:

```
json_data = json.loads(str(yourData))
```

After that, in your case, the outermost key is "output", and it is another dict, so just use `json_data['output']` to access the content inside.

For other keys inside of the "output", like "generic", you can see it is an array with the [] brackets. use `json_data['output'][index]` first to get the content inside, then use the same method you access a dict to access the content inside of keys like this.

Comment: This makes way too much sense thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad it helps, it is also one of the issues I encountered when I first learn Python.

Answer (score 1):

They key here is that the Traceback error indicates an issue with indexing a "List"

This is because a "List" type is a valid JSON type, and `generic` contains a list of length 1, with a dict inside!

```
>>> payload['output']['generic']['text']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
>>> type(payload['output']['generic'])
<class 'list'>
>>> len(payload['output']['generic'])
1
>>> payload['output']['generic'][0]
{'response_type': 'text', 'text': 'hi'}
>>> type(payload['output']['generic'][0])
<class 'dict'>
>>> payload['output']['generic'][0]['text']
'hi'
>>>
```

So, given your expected input JSON format, you will need to know how to index in to pull each required data point.

There are a few packages, glom is one, that will help you deal with missing values from API generated JSON.

Comment: Amazing thanks makes perfect sense, I was trying to access just using [1] as it was the second item in the list, didn't realise that's what I could do!

Comment: Great! I'm sure you'll see this one more than once :-) Good luck!